# Can't install or remove packages

Tags: software-installation, uninstall

I'm getting this error:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package `linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic' contains empty filename
```

I think it might have some thing to do with an old kernel, but I can't uninstall it with `sudo apt-get remove` or `purge` since it keeps erroring.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the following:

> `rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic.list`

Then update your system.

Comment: I did this, then ran sudo apt-get update. It kept erroring with the same error, so I kept removing the relevant .list file. Finally, it updated and I was able to reinstall my broken package. Do you know why this method works?

Answer (score -2):

Try this solution:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg
```

Backup:

```
sudo cp diversions diversions.bak
sudo cp diversions-old diversions-old.bak
```

Then make diversions back to old:

```
sudo cp diversions-old diversions
```

Now try update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then re-install your package:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall packagename
```

---

#### Another possible solution: Quoted from http://www.richud.com/wiki/Ubuntu_Dpkg:_unrecoverable_fatal_error

```
sudo gedit -w /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Remove the whole section of `linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic`

Then run

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

You should then get still the initial errors "dpkg: warning: files list file for package `xxxxxxxxxxx' missing

Now run

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Yet again you should see "dpkg: warning: files list file for package `xxxxxxxxxxx' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.".

Now do this replacing xxxxxxx with all the package names above that appear.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: These didn't work, but thank you for your answer.

Comment: So why downvoting?

Comment: That is not me :)